# is there any way to include terraform-aws-provider-resource in container definition JSON Document?

Tags: json, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

### Overview

I am building AWS-ECS-Service-container using terraform.
terraform aws_ecs_task_definition

> example **task_definition_kafka.tf**

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task_definition_kafka" {
  container_definitions    = file("./task_definition_kafka.json")
}
```

> example **task_definition_kafka.json**

```
[
  {    

    "cpu": 256,
    "memory": 768,
    "portMappings": [
      { 
        "hostPort": 7002,
        "containerPort": 7002,
        "protocol": "tcp"
      }
    ],
    "essential": true,
    "environment" : [   
      { "name" : "SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL", "value" : "${aws_ecs_task_definition.aws_ecs_task_definition_kafka.private_ip}:2181" },
    ]
  }
]
```

### Main Question

In above json file i want to use **${aws_ecs_task_definition.aws_ecs_task_definiton_kafka.private_ip} syntax for getting private_ip from terraform-aws-provider-resource**

Is it possible ?

Comment: You would need to either use Terraform's templating (with `templatefile` or the `template_file` data source) or interpolate your container definition by sticking it in a HEREDOC directly in a `.tf` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`templatefile`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html) to ask Terraform to read a file *and* interpret it as a Terraform template:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task_definition_kafka" {
  container_definitions = templatefile("${path.module}/task_definition_kafka.json", {
    kafka_private_ip = aws_ecs_task_definition.aws_ecs_task_definition_kafka.private_ip
  })
}
```

Although the external file is interpreted as a normal [Terraform string template](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#string-templates), it looks like your goal is to produce a JSON string in this case, so [it's better to use the `jsonencode` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html#generating-json-or-yaml-from-a-template) than to construct the JSON data piecemeal using multiple template directives. Here's how to write your `task_definition_kafka.json` following that advice:

```
${jsonencode([
  {
    cpu: 256,
    memory: 768,
    portMappings: [
      {
        hostPort: 7002,
        containerPort: 7002,
        protocol: "tcp",
      },
    ],
    essential: true,
    environment: [
      {
        name: "SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL",
        value: kafka_private_ip,
      },
    ],
  },
])}
```

The main advantage of generating the whole JSON string at once using a single `jsonencode` call is that the result is guaranteed to be valid JSON syntax without you needing to take special efforts to encode each part separately. `jsonencode` can accept a value of any type from the Terraform language and convert it into equivalent JSON, so you can use [Terraform expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html) to dynamically generate parts of the data structure using the template variables passed to the second argument of `templatefile`, like `kafka_private_ip` in the above example.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can create template data file and pass variables that you want to use in **vars**.

For example,

```
data "template_file" "task-definition-kafka" {
  template = "${file("./task_definition_kafka.json")}"
  vars = {
    kafka_private_ip = "${aws_instance.kafka.private_ip}"
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "kafka" {
  container_definitions = "${data.template_file.task-definition-kafka.rendered}"
}
```

so your **task_definition_kafka.json** file will be:

```
[
  {    

    "cpu": 256,
    "memory": 768,
    "portMappings": [
      { 
        "hostPort": 7002,
        "containerPort": 7002,
        "protocol": "tcp"
      }
    ],
    "essential": true,
    "environment" : [   
      { "name" : "SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL", "value" : "${kafka_private_ip}:2181" },
    ]
  }
]
```

for more information you can check template provider, https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/template/latest/docs/data-sources/file